# How can I verify the SHA256 hash of 0.10.3 “Wolfram Warptangent” on macOS?

Tags: cryptography, macos, hash-verification, wolfram-warptangent

How can I verify the SHA256 [hash published](https://getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt) for the official 0.10.3 "Wolfram Warptangent” release matches the file that I [downloaded](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) for macOS, 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS:

1. Downloading the tar.bz file. I will assume it is located in the normal "Downloads" directory, and it's name is `monero-mac-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2`. Other names/locations are fine but you'll have to adjust the process accordingly.
2. Open Terminal. Easiest way is `⌘+spacebar` and type "Terminal", then hit enter.
3. Change to the Downloads directory. Type `cd ~/Downloads` and hit enter.
4. Get the Sha-256 Checksum. Type `shasum -a 256 monero-mac-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2` and hit enter.
5. Compare it with the checksum on the Monero page.

On Linux (tested on Ubuntu 16.04) the command is `sha256sum` rather than `shasum -a 256`.

On Windows, the command is `pinch nose, scrunch eyes, and hope everything is good as you unzip the file`. Just kidding. I don't know the Windows command though.