# How can I verify the SHA256 hash of 0.10.3 “Wolfram Warptangent” on FreeBSD?

Tags: cryptography, freebsd, hash-verification

How can I verify the SHA256 listed in this [GPG-signed message](https://getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt) for the official Monero 0.10.3 release matches the file that I downloaded for [FreeBSD](https://getmonero.org/downloads/), 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for Linux and FreeBSD is similar to that for macOS, described here: [How can I verify the SHA256 hash of 0.10.3 “Wolfram Warptangent” on macOS?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3927/how-can-i-verify-the-sha256-hash-of-0-10-3-wolfram-warptangent-on-macos)

For FreeBSD, use the command `sha256sum <filename>` in the terminal and compare the output to the checksums on the Monero webpage.